# Setting IFS to ignore whitespaces while reading from a here-string

Tags: bash, ifs

I have a little problem with IFS to distinguish packages and the distribution.
Now I wanted to add the version number of CentOS, but the problem is that CentOS and the number 6 are separated by IFS.
My question is, how do I get IFS to ignore spaces and see them as a single value?
Thanks in advance :)

```
...

PACKET_MANAGERS=(
    "Debian|package:package:package|apt:dpkg-query|"
    "CentOS 6|package:package:package|yum:rpm|${CentOS_6_REPO}"
    ...
)
...
   for system in ${PACKET_MANAGERS[@]}
do
    IFS='|' read -r -a data <<< $system
    debug "Testing ${system} => ${data[0]}"

    if echo "${SYSTEM_NAME}" | grep "${data[0]}" &>/dev/null; then
        SYSTEM_NAME_DETECTED="${data[0]}"
    else
        continue
    fi

...

done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote `${PACKET_MANAGERS[@]}`:

```
for system in "${PACKET_MANAGERS[@]}"
```

Otherwise, word-splitting will be done on the result of expanding the array expression, so each word in each element of the array will be a separate iteration of the `for` loop. Using `[@]` will make each array element be a separate word in the result.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer but unfortunately it doesn't work with "$system"?

Comment: You also need to quote `"${PACKET_MANAGERS[@]}"`. [ShellCheck](https://shellcheck.net) points out both these issues.

Comment: You only need to quote `$system` to work around bugs in older version of `bash`.  The here string isn't supposed to undergo word-splitting.

Comment: How else could this be implemented?

Comment: @jamefane I've updated the answer to say that you need to quote `${PACKET_MANAGERS[@]}`